# when I use @NotNull, @NotBlank and @Valid together I am getting error message even though I am passing the values

Tags: spring-boot, validation, controller

I am using @NotBlank and @NotNull in the DTO class. I am passing the values in the firstName, lastName, and userRole. Still getting an error message.

**UserDTO**

```
package com.pocketxtra.eventmanager.controller.dto;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.pocketxtra.eventmanager.service.domain.Gender;
import com.pocketxtra.eventmanager.service.domain.Role;
import com.pocketxtra.eventmanager.service.domain.UserType;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Pattern;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;


@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class UserDTO {
    String id;
    private String contact;
    @NotBlank(message = "First name is mandatory")
    private String firstName;
    @NotBlank(message = "Last name is mandatory")
    private String lastName;
    @NotNull(message = "Role is mandatory")
    private Role userRole;
    private UserType userType;
    @Valid
    @JsonProperty("crew")
    private CrewDTO crewDTO;
}
```

**CrewDTO**

```
package com.pocketxtra.eventmanager.controller.dto;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.pocketxtra.eventmanager.service.domain.WeekDay;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.util.Date;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class CrewDTO extends UserDTO {
    @NotNull(message = "Date of Birth is mandatory")
    private Date dob;
    @Valid
    @NotNull(message = "Education details is mandatory")
    @JsonProperty("education")
    private EducationDTO educationDTO;
    @NotNull(message = "Primary location is mandatory")
    private String primaryLocation;
}
```

**UserController.signup**

```
@PostMapping("/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<String> signup(@RequestBody @Valid UserDTO userDTO) {
       // some code here...
}
```

**Postman Request**

```
        {
  "contact": "3245345451",
  "firstName": "Aman",
  "lastName": "Kumar",
  "userRole": "CREW",
  "crew": {
    "primaryLocation": "abcdncandkjcn",
    "dob": "1999-09-16T08:33:59.309Z",
    "education": {
      "college": "ABC",
      "course": "BCD",
      "city": "KANPUR"
    }
  }
}
```

I am passing the values of firstName, lastName, and userRole in the controller using Postman and still getting the error message: `First Name is mandatory, Last Name is mandatory and Role is mandatory`. Can anyone tell me what is the issue here?

Comment: Please, add your postman request body also

Comment: When I remove @Valid from CrewDTO then it works fine.

Comment: Try to put "@Valid" before "@RequestBody"

Comment: Not working. I found this issue when I used @Valid in UserDTO.

Comment: If you used it in UserDTO, then it's the same as "RequestBody" left, "Valid" right- I.e. validation could occur before values from request body are set. So please try changing order of annotations

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution. I am extending UserDTO in CrewDTO. After adding @Valid, it validates all the members of the crewDTO object and also members of the parent class.